# How to install iGraph python package on Windows?

Tags: python, package, igraph

Hello I'm a beginner in coding in python and I'm trying to install iGraph but I keep getting errors. I have the python version 3.5.1 and I tried to manually download and install iGraph using directions from the official website and also I used PyCharm to automatically download the package but I every time I get some kind of error.

The latest error I get is:

#### DeprecationWarning: To avoid name collision with the igraph project, this visualization library has been renamed to 'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.

I tried renaming the commands to jgraph but I get other errors that the package was not found.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out on this one

Thanks

Comment: Most likely you are installing the wrong package; you need `python-igraph` and not `igraph`. Use one of the precompiled installers from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error and spent hours resolving. Finally did following.

```
pip install jgraph
```

Change code to:

```
import jgraph as ig
```

I have python(x,y) and the code ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed the wrong igraph library.

Maybe you have installed this igraph (0.2.1), while this igraph (0.7.1) is the one you need (and the well-known iGraph).

After you've installed [`pip`](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/), just run below command:

```
sudo pip uninstall igraph
```

Then install the python-igraph-0.7.1 package, using either `pip` or `apt-get` as mentioned in comments below:

```
sudo pip install python-igraph
```